# Include escrow account in my Market Place Website

Tags: paypal, payments

I want to build a marketplace in my website, and I want to supervise all the transactions in this Market Place, thus I want the buyer to put his money in my escrow account before paying the seller.

I thought to use PayPal, so what do I need to include in my User Interface?

My website's PayPal User Name?

Any serial # ?

Comment: If you're asking how to allow people to manually send you a payment over Paypal, then all you need is to give them your paypal account ID (email address). And this belongs on webapps not webmasters.